# setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true on ubuntu

Tags: java, netbeans

ı am using the campus wifi for my development and recently i moved to ubuntu and my netbean cant cant connect to internet becouse of the school proxy. ı had the same problem while on windows and i solved it by entering this command in the cmd "setx _JAVA_OPTIONS -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true" have tried doing the same on ubuntu but it aint working. how do i go about this .ı will really appreciate your help. thank in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this option through the config file: **`<Netbeans Directory>/etc/netbeans.conf`**

*Append* the option to **`netbeans_default_options`**.

The line should look like this:

```
netbeans_default_options="[many other options here …] -J-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
```

If this doesn't work, please check the Netbeans Log for any issues. There could be an security / configuration related issue too.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in eclipse ,So i set it at IDE level.For net beans you follow the steps.

1. Open NetBeans, go to Tools then Options menu item.
2. Click the General tab.
3. Select Manual Proxy Settings.
4. Fill in the IP address or Hostname of the proxy server you want to connect  to and enter the port number which is being used by the proxy server.
5. Click Ok to close the dialog box

I hope this helps you out.